# how to insert object to Specific index in object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing, push

I want to insert object Specific index.

I research push and splice but I couldn't find a solution.

```
var collection = [ {id:"123"} ,{id:"567"}, {id:"999"} ]
```

The result I'm looking forward to is

result :

```
[ {id:"123"} ,{id:"567"}, {id:"1111"}, {id:"999"} ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
var collection = [{id:"123"} ,{id:"567"}, {id:"999"}];
collection.splice(2, 0, { id: "1111" });
console.log(collection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I tried mycode, but I asked you a question because I'm sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice method of Array
collection.splice(index, value, numberOfElWillBeRemoved, numberOfElWillBeAdded)
For more detail: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trow array:

```
var collection = [{ id: "123" }, { id: "567" }, { id: "999" }];

for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    console.log(collection[i]);
}
```

And change the array length

```
collection.length = 4
```

Then replace location of any string.
Just make new same array and replace the var

```
var newArray = collection;
collection[3] = newArray[2];
```

Now 2 index is free.